# Detect Absolute position on Elan Touchpad

Tags: python, hardware, touchpad

I would like to know how exactly to detect absolution position of touches on an Elan Touchpad. The Elan settings app does show a window called smart area that is capable of achieving this. But i'd like to know the possibility of said detection, especially using Python. But anything else is welcome too.